# width of site that is loaded in iframe

Tags: iframe, width, document

I have a iframe in my site that i load to it different sites (all in my domain).

I need to create a div that will cover the hole site inside the iframe, even when the user uses the scrolling bars.

For that i need to get the width and height of the current site in the iframe.

To get the height i used :

```
$(document).height()
```

How can i get the width?? i tried

```
$(document).width()
```

But didnt work, any ideas?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this

```
$("#myFrame").load(function () {
        widthOfSiteInIframe = this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
    });
```